# MailApp.sendEmail function gives a generic error

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a budget sheet, which need to be populated in africa, by people without a google account.
I share the google sheet via a link and they can update the content. When they finished the updating, I would like to give them a possibility to send it to a small distribution list via a script

```js
function sendReport() {  
    var message = {  
    to: "user@domain.org",  
        subject: "Budget proposal",  
    body: "Hi team,\n\nPlease find the budget attached.\n\nThank you,\n",  
    name: "Budget",  
    From: 'user@gmail.com',  
    attachments: [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("Budget")] 
    }  
    MailApp.sendEmail(message);  
}
```

This works fine as long as I m logged in via any google account, but for a non google account, I get the following error:
**Script sendReport experienced an error Details**

The amount of data is too much for a form (but in a form I seem to be able to ask them to send a mail, so I wonder where I go wrong...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MailApp.sendEmail(message)` does not accept a `From` parameter, so that part of the object `message` gets ignored.

So if your account executes this script, you send it from your own domain email. Since it requires a google email to send a message, non-google accounts cannot execute this script.

**Reference:**

[MailApp.sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object))

Comment: Also, please see [google apps script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)

Comment: Thank you Carlos_M & Baby_Boy. So may be I need to run something in the background which is triggered by an update to send an email... As some of the add ons can send an email like on a Contact Me form. The difference is that I don't want to send based on a single row, but I would like to send the full spreadsheet... Mmmm I need to do some more thinking, but your comments are much appreciated...